# OpenCart 2 OCMod not makeing changes to language file

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

Why does this opencart 2 OCMod not work?

```
<modification>

    <file name="catalog/language/english/english.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[
                $_['text_home'] = '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>';
                ]]></search>
            <add  position="replace"><![CDATA[
                $_['text_home'] = 'Home'; 
                ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

</modification>
```

I upload it and refresh the mods cache, but my changes do not appear.

Comment: never mind - I faound the issue, OCMod changed the file 'name' attribute to 'path'

Answer (score -1):

```
Add Search Tag "<search position="replace">"
<modification>

<file name="catalog/language/english/english.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
            $_['text_home'] = '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>';
            ]]></search>
        <add  position="replace"><![CDATA[
            $_['text_home'] = 'Home'; 
            ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

Comment: this may work with VQMod, but not OCmod as the positoin attribute is moved to the add tag in OCMod, also, as I noted, the file attribute 'name' is now changed to 'path'

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
<modification>
    <name><![CDATA[<font color="#0000"><b>Home link</font>]]></name>
    <version><![CDATA[<b>1.0</b>]]></version>
    <code>home_link</code>
    <author><![CDATA[<font color="#CC0000"><b>zec Blackbeard</b></font>]]></author>
    <link><![CDATA[abcd.com]]></link>

    <file path="catalog/language/english/english.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$_['text_home']             = '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>';]]></search>
            <add  position="replace"><![CDATA[$_['text_home'] = 'Home';]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

</modification>
```

You have mode sily mistake. In `ocmod`, file `name` attribute does not work. You need to replace with `path`.

You need to change following line.

**Find**

`<file name="catalog/language/english/english.php">`

**Replace with**

`<file path="catalog/language/english/english.php">`